# What does python format function without place holders do?

Tags: python

I just started learning python. And read about python [format](https://pyformat.info/).
Now one of the tutorial I am following have below example.

```
print(format(16,'x'))
```

It gives output

> 10

What is this value 10 signifies and what does this format function do without a placeholder text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"x"` means that the value (number 16 in this case) should be converted to hexadecimal, using lower case letters for digits larger than 9.

The hexadecimal representation for 16 is 10 - this is why your example prints `10`.

Also note that the buit-in `format` function is different than `str.format`.

More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format

Answer (score 3):

`format()` doesn't take placeholders, *because it is not a string template*. You are confusing that function with the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
>>> value = 16
>>> "This is a template with a placeholder: {:x}".format(value)
'This is a template with a placeholder: 10'
>>> f"This is a formatted string literal with placeholder: {value:x}"
'This is a formatted string literal with placeholder: 10'
```

Note that the above also outputs `10` for a value of 16! That's because the `{...}` placeholder contains some extra information, the `:x` part. More on that below.

The [`format()` **function**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) does the work of combining instructions given in a placeholder with the value that is to be placed in that placeholder; everything after the `:` inside the `{}` is given as the second argument to that function.

So for the above formatted string literal, the contents of the `{value:x}` placeholder are replaced by the return value of `format(value, 'x')`:

```
>>> format(value, 'x')
'10'
```

The `'x'` value is called the *formatting spec*, and what you want to study here, then, is what [formatting specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), which tells you that `x` produces the *lowercase [hexadecimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)* of integer numbers. 16 decimal, in hexadecimal, is `10`.

From the formatting specification documentation:

> `'x'`
>   Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lower-case letters for the digits above 9.

There is an upper-case variant, `'X'` too, but for `16` that doesn't make any difference because none of the `a-f` or `A-F` 'digits' are used in that value, but you can see the difference with `42`:

```
>>> value = 42
>>> format(value, 'x')
'2a'
>>> format(value, 'X')
'2A'
```

It actually depends on the type of `value` what formatting specifiers are supported. The [`datetime.datetime()` and `datetime.date()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) have their own formatting specifiers!

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> format(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S, %A %B %d %y")
'16:36:04, Monday November 25 19'
>>> format(date.today(), "%Y-%m-%d")
'2019-11-25'
```

The formatting specifications for the standard types are all described in the *mini language specification* I linked to; you can do a lot of powerful things with those, including text alignments or to constrain long text.

In fact, you can give your own types full support for custom formats by giving them a [`__format__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__). `format(value, spec)` *basically* calls `value.__format__(spec)`, adding a few sanity checks.

So to come full circle, integers have a `__format__` method:

```
>>> value
42
>>> type(value)
<class 'int'>
>>> value.__format__('x')
'2a'
>>> value.__format__('X')
'2A'
```

but we usually just use `format()` or string templates.

Note that string templates have some more features that `format()` doesn't take care of. You can also use the `!s`, `!r`, or `!a` *conversions* in your placeholder; these add a call to [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii), respectively. They are super-handy when you have values that don't have good formatting support or you want to get good debugging information out of them.

And talking of debugging, if you use Python 3.8 or newer, you can add `=` after an expression in an formatted string literal, and the expression itself will also be included in the output:

```
>>> f"This is the value: {value:X}"
'This is the value: 2A'
>>> f"This is the value: {value=:X}"
'This is the value: value=2A'
```

That's especially helpful when you use more complex expressions in there; spaces are preserved:

```
>>> f"This is the value: {value * 17 = :X}"
'This is the value: value * 17 = 2CA'
```